# React Native - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_context8.t0.response.data.message')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, redux, axios

I am trying to recreate a simple React-Native MERN, todo application with a User register and login interface connecting to a Node and Mongo backend server.  I am having trouble connecting the backend server using axios.  I see other similar Stackoverflow issues but none that have solved my problem.

I am hoping that someone would be able to provide some specifics on what could be causing the issue or how to better troubleshoot.

I am able to start both the front end and can see the Registration screen on the android emmulator.  The backend server and connection to the Mongodb is also up and working.

After starting the client and entering the registration information the system fails.  I can tell that the connection is not being made but not sure why.  I have checked the routes on both sides pretty closely and believe that they are correct but maybe I missed something.

The error message including some console logs I added to troubleshoot are as follows.

```
Action (Redux) - Start - Platform.OS =  android
Action (Redux) - Start - serverUrl =  http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/v1
Android Running app on AOSP on IA Emulator
Action (Redux) - register before axios post- formData =  FormData {
  "_parts": Array [
    Array [
      "name",
      "jj",
    ],
    Array [
      "email",
      "jj",
    ],
    Array [
      "password",
      "jj",
    ],
    Array [
      "avatar",
      Object {
        "name": "",
        "type": null,
        "uri": "",
      },
    ],
  ],
}
Action (Redux) - register before axios post- serverUrl/register =  http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/v1/register
Action (Redux) - register before axios post- dispatch =  [Function dispatch]
Action (Redux) - register - The request was made but no response was received
Action (Redux) - register - error.request =  XMLHttpRequest {
  "DONE": 4,
  "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
  "LOADING": 3,
  "OPENED": 1,
  "UNSENT": 0,
  "_aborted": false,
  "_cachedResponse": undefined,
  "_hasError": true,
  "_headers": Object {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
  "_incrementalEvents": false,
  "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": Object {},
  "_method": "POST",
  "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/v1/register",
  "_performanceLogger": PerformanceLogger {
    "_closed": false,
    "_extras": Object {},
    "_pointExtras": Object {},
    "_points": Object {
      "initializeCore_end": 1666812289789,
      "initializeCore_start": 1666812289693,
    },
    "_timespans": Object {
      "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://10.0.0.88:19000/logs": Object {
        "endExtras": undefined,
        "endTime": 1666812290557,
        "startExtras": undefined,
        "startTime": 1666812290355,
        "totalTime": 202,
      },
      "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/v1/me": Object {
        "endExtras": undefined,
        "endTime": 1666812290624,
        "startExtras": undefined,
        "startTime": 1666812290510,
        "totalTime": 114,
      },
      "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/v1/register": Object {
        "startExtras": undefined,
        "startTime": 1666812300206,
      },
    },
  },
  "_requestId": null,
  "_response": "Binary FormData part needs a content-type header.",
  "_responseType": "",
  "_sent": true,
  "_subscriptions": Array [],
  "_timedOut": false,
  "_trackingName": "unknown",
  "_url": "http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/v1/register",
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseHeaders": undefined,
  "status": 0,
  "timeout": 0,
  "upload": XMLHttpRequestEventTarget {},
  "withCredentials": true,
}
Action (Redux) - register - error.response =  undefined
Action (Redux) - register - error.request =  XMLHttpRequest {
  "DONE": 4,
  "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2,
  "LOADING": 3,
  "OPENED": 1,
  "UNSENT": 0,
  "_aborted": false,
  "_cachedResponse": undefined,
  "_hasError": true,
  "_headers": Object {
    "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
  },
  "_incrementalEvents": false,
  "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": Object {},
  "_method": "POST",
  "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/v1/register",
  "_performanceLogger": PerformanceLogger {
    "_closed": false,
    "_extras": Object {},
    "_pointExtras": Object {},
    "_points": Object {
      "initializeCore_end": 1666812289789,
      "initializeCore_start": 1666812289693,
    },
    "_timespans": Object {
      "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://10.0.0.88:19000/logs": Object {
        "endExtras": undefined,
        "endTime": 1666812290557,
        "startExtras": undefined,
        "startTime": 1666812290355,
        "totalTime": 202,
      },
      "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/v1/me": Object {
        "endExtras": undefined,
        "endTime": 1666812290624,
        "startExtras": undefined,
        "startTime": 1666812290510,
        "totalTime": 114,
      },
      "network_XMLHttpRequest_http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/v1/register": Object {
        "startExtras": undefined,
        "startTime": 1666812300206,
      },
    },
  },
  "_requestId": null,
  "_response": "Binary FormData part needs a content-type header.",
  "_responseType": "",
  "_sent": true,
  "_subscriptions": Array [],
  "_timedOut": false,
  "_trackingName": "unknown",
  "_url": "http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/v1/register",
  "readyState": 4,
  "responseHeaders": undefined,
  "status": 0,
  "timeout": 0,
  "upload": XMLHttpRequestEventTarget {},
  "withCredentials": true,
}
Action (Redux) - register - error.message =  Network Error
```

Below is the client side axios code with all but code essential to registration removed.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Platform } from 'react-native'

console.log ("Action (Redux) - Start - Platform.OS = ", Platform.OS);
let serverUrl = '';

{Platform.OS == 'android'
? serverUrl = 'http://10.0.2.2:4000/api/v1'
: serverUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1'
}
//const serverUrl = "https://todo-app-server-for-free.herokuapp.com/api/v1";
console.log ("Action (Redux) - Start - serverUrl = ", serverUrl);

export const register = (formData) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: "registerRequest" });

    console.log ("Action (Redux) - register before axios post- formData = ", formData);
    console.log ("Action (Redux) - register before axios post- serverUrl/register = ", `${serverUrl}/register`);
    console.log ("Action (Redux) - register before axios post- dispatch = ", dispatch);
    const { data } = await axios.post(`${serverUrl}/register`, formData, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    });
    console.log ("Action (Redux) - register after axios post - data = ", data);
    dispatch({ type: "registerSuccess", payload: data });
  } } catch (error) {
    
    if (error.response){
      console.log("Action (Redux) - register - in 1st catch - registerFailure");
    //  dispatch({
    //    type: "registerFailure",
    //    payload: error.response.data.message,
    //  });
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // Error details are stored in err.reqeust
      console.log("Action (Redux) - register - The request was made but no response was received");
      console.log("Action (Redux) - register - error.request = ", error.request);
    } else {
      // Some other errors
      console.log("Action (Redux) - register - Non-descript error provided!")
      console.log('Action (Redux) - register - error.message = ', error.message);
    }
    console.log("Action (Redux) - register - error.response = ",error.response);
    //console.log("Action (Redux) - register - error.response.data = ", error.response.data);
    //console.log("Action (Redux) - register - error.response.status = ", error.response.status);
    //console.log("Action (Redux) - register - error.response.headers = ", error.response.headers);
    console.log("Action (Redux) - register - error.request = ", error.request);
    console.log("Action (Redux) - register - error.message = ", error.message);
  }
};
```

This is what my backend code looks like with non essential code removed:
server.js

```
import { config } from "dotenv";
import { app } from "./express.js";
import { connectDatabase } from "./config/database.js";

import cloudinary from "cloudinary";

config({
  path: "./config/config.env",
});
cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUD_API_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_API_SECRET,
});
connectDatabase();

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port " + process.env.PORT);
});
```

express.js

```
import express from "express";
import path from "path";

import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";
//import compress from "compression";
import cors from "cors";
import fileUpload from "express-fileupload";

import userRoutes from "./routers/User.js";

export const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(cookieParser());
//app.use(compress());
app.use(
  fileUpload({
    limits: { fileSize: 50 * 1024 * 1024 },
    useTempFiles: true,
  })
);
app.use(cors());

app.use("/", userRoutes);

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Server is working");
});
```

User Route

```
import express from "express";
import {
  addTask,
  forgetPassword,
  getMyProfile,
  login,
  logout,
  register,
  removeTask,
  resetPassword,
  updatePassword,
  updateProfile,
  updateTask,
  verify,
} from "../controllers/User.js";

const api = process.env.API_URL;

const router = express.Router();

router.route("/api/v1/register").post(register);

export default router;
```

User Controller

```
import { User } from "../models/users.js";
import { sendMail } from "../utils/sendMail.js";
import { sendToken } from "../utils/sendToken.js";
import cloudinary from "cloudinary";
import fs from "fs";

export const register = async (req, res) => {
  console.log("Controllers - User - Register req = ", reg)
  try {
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    const avatar = req.files.avatar.tempFilePath;

    let user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (user) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ success: false, message: "User already exists" });
    }

    const otp = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);

    const mycloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(avatar);

    fs.rmSync("./tmp", { recursive: true });

    user = await User.create({
      name,
      email,
      password,
      avatar: {
        public_id: mycloud.public_id,
        url: mycloud.secure_url,
      },
      otp,
      otp_expiry: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.OTP_EXPIRE * 60 * 1000),
    });

    await sendMail(email, "Verify your account", `Your OTP is ${otp}`);

    sendToken(
      res,
      user,
      201,
      "OTP sent to your email, please verify your account"
    );
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
  }
};
```

Front end Registration code

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Avatar, Button } from 'react-native-paper'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { register } from '../redux/action';
import mime from 'mime';

const Register = ({ navigation, route }) => {


    const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState("");
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const handleImage = () => {
        navigation.navigate("camera", {
            updateProfile: false
        })
    };

    const registerHandler = () => {
        const myForm = new FormData();
        myForm.append("name", name);
        myForm.append("email", email);
        myForm.append("password", password);
        myForm.append("avatar", {
            uri: avatar,
            type: mime.getType(avatar),
            name: avatar.split("/").pop()
        })

        dispatch(register(myForm));
    }

    useEffect(() => {

        if (route.params) {
            if (route.params.image) {
                setAvatar(route.params.image)
            }
        }

    }, [route])


    return (
        <View
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
            }}
        >
            <Avatar.Image
                size={100}
                source={{ uri: avatar ? avatar : null }}
                style={{ backgroundColor: "#900" }}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleImage}>
                <Text style={{ color: "#900" }}>Change Photo</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <View style={{ width: "70%" }}>
                <TextInput
                    style={Styles.input}
                    placeholder="Name"
                    value={name}
                    onChangeText={setName}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={Styles.input}
                    placeholder="Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChangeText={setEmail}
                />
                <TextInput
                    secureTextEntry
                    style={Styles.input}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    value={password}
                    onChangeText={setPassword}
                />
            </View>

            <Button
                disabled={
                    !email || !password || !name
                }
                style={Styles.btn}
                onPress={registerHandler}
            >
                <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}>Register</Text>
            </Button>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("login")}>
                <Text
                    style={{
                        color: "#900",
                        height: 30,
                        margin: 20,
                    }}
                >
                    Have an Account, Login
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}

export default Register



const Styles = StyleSheet.create({

    input: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: "#b5b5b5",
        padding: 10,
        paddingLeft: 15,
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginVertical: 15,
        fontSize: 15,
    },

    btn: {
        backgroundColor: "#900",
        padding: 5,
        width: "70%",
    },
})
```

Comment: Note that I have updated the Error message after removing redux dispatch code and console logs of undefined values.  This should reduce my error message to just the axios issue.  From this I see two possible sources, one is the last line of the message indicates, "Network Error".  Also, inside the error message is says that, "Binary FormData part needs a content-type header", but in another place is shows that I am using form data.  I also updated axios to 1.1.3 as somewhere I saw that version 1 of axios may help these kinds of errors.

Comment: I see another Stack overflow issue where Android has a problem with "http" protocol.  This could be resolved by just adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in AndroidManifest.xml.   I do not have an xml file.  If this is the fix, where would I add this in a React Native App? As I am using the emulator would this still be a problem?  If so, how do I work around this?

<application
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
 >
</application>